# How do I configure Persona.ly Callbacks?

Tags: java, android, firebase, callback

Could you comment an example of some callback code for Persona.ly? Their documentation is hard to understand! I'm not sure how to add callbacks natively for both these platforms (I don't want to use a server, I want to make Callbacks native on the device).

```
//Code for Persona.ly
@Override
public void onAdRewarded(Impression impression) {

// user saw the full ad and we can reward him with currency
int amount = impression.getRewardedAmount();

// optional values
boolean hasRewaredAmount = impression.hasRewardedAmount();
boolean isRewardedVideo = impression.isRewardedVideo();
boolean isRewardedPlayable = impression.isRewardedPlayable();
}
```

If native callbacks aren't possible, could you show me how to implement Firebase callbacks (ie. No server except firebase, after callback adds points to user balance). Thanks!

Comment: https://persona.ly/knowledge/?ht_kb=android-integration-rephrase

Comment: shmosel - Thanks for the amazing quick reply! Unfortunately I have checked the knowledge base already...I can not figure out where exactly to paste this code into my app. Would it go outside the main function?

Comment: What main function? Aren't you making an Android app?

Comment: @shmosel - Yes, is this to be placed in the function that launches the offerwall?

Comment: I didn't read the docs.